# Chrome mobile sometimes renders element incorrectly

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile, layout

I'm writing a "responsive design" layout and it's been kind of a headache so far. I decided to use the `:before` and `vertical-align: middle;` workaround to vertically align some text inside 'buttons', and it works on everything, except one button! The thing is, on refresh, Chrome Mobile will sometimes render it correctly, and sometimes it won't; it seems arbitrary, I haven't been able to find a pattern.

Here's how it should not look:

[image]

Here's how it should look:

[image]

Here's the relevant markup:

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="/login">
        <span class='button-container'>
            <span class="button-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
            </span><br/>
            <span class="button-label">
                Log In
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <a href="/signup">
        <span class='button-container'>
            <span class="button-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>
            </span><br/>
            <span class="button-label">
                Join Us!
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.button
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.button a
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
.button a:before //So its contents vertically-align
{
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
}
.button-container
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.button-icon
{
    font-size: 180%;
}
.button-label
{
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

It only happens with the "Log In" button (but I included two of them in case it helps). The buttons are contained within a div that has `text-align: right;`, in case that's relevant.

It renders well on Firefox Mobile, and on desktop, of course. I tested it on Chrome Beta v42, and the most recent version of regular Chrome Mobile, I guess maybe it's a Webkit thing, but I wonder if it's a known issue, and if there are any workarounds, or at least an explanation as to why it happens.

Comment: Is there a -webkit- attribute you can try?

Comment: Hmm, I think all of these CSS features are compatible with old browsers, so why the -webkit-, may I ask? Whatever the case, I'm using prefix-free.js, which I think would cover any missing -webkit- prefix.

Comment: They should all be, I don't see any that would need that attribute, but since it seems to be a problem related to Chrome, thought that it might offer a new look.

Comment: Yeah, it seems Chrome-related, but where could I add a -webkit-, just to test? I wouldn't know, honestly, ha.

Comment: You would prepend the modifier like so `-webkit-vertical-align: middle;` Im not 100% sure there even needs to be one, as this is the first time Ive ever even seen the `vertical-align` tag. But it never hurts to try something random.

Comment: Haha, I've tried a lot of random things already. And I just tried that. No luck! I think vertical-align is pretty common. It aligns inline elements that are next to each other.

Comment: Hmm, the only other thing I could possibly think of is just a bug in Chrome. You haven't noticed a pattern yet right?

Comment: Well, it probably is. No, I haven't. I think that maybe Chrome isn't rendering the :before pseudo-element sometimes, but I'm not sure. And if it's so, I'm not sure why either. Thanks for helping, though.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but if you figure it out, do you mind letting us know?

Comment: It's okay, it's a weird issue, I think. I sure will, if no one beats me to it. (and if I do figure it out)